# protobuf 2.5.0 and raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3

Im currently trying to install hadoop 2.7.2 on my new raspberry pi 3, but I'm running into issues getting protobuf setup.

I'm currently getting the tar.gz from https://github.com/google/protobuf/archive/v2.5.0.tar.gz

and then running the following.

```
$ tar xvf v2.5.0.tar.gz
$ cd protobuf-2.5.0
$ ./autogen.sh
```

When I get here though, I run into this issue

```
Google Test not present.  Fetching gtest-1.5.0 from the web...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1586  100  1586    0     0  15603      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15702
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What am i missing here? Has anybody who has successfully setup protobuf and hadoop on a rpi3 encountered something similar to this?

Comment: Looks like you have a bad download, have you tried to download it again?

Comment: I've tried redownloading and it multiple times to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using protobuf 2.5.0, but I suspect it's because hadoop requires that version and won't work with 3.0.0.

I'd suggest just getting stuff from github, like this. In general, piping the output of curl to a shell is a bad habit to have (from a security point of view). It's OK in this particular case, of course, but I took this opportunity to point out a bad habit that may bite you in the future.

```
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest
cd googletest
git checkout release-1.5.0
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf
cd protobuf
git checkout v2.5.0
ln -s ../googletest gtest
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j 4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

If you also want to build the python bindings:

```
cd python
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

The autogen.sh checks if gtest directory exists and if absent, try to get `http://googletest.googlecode.com/files/gtest-1.5.0.tar.bz2`. However the URL does not exist so that results in 404 error.

Thus try this in protobuf-2.5.0 directory, before executing autogen.sh, like this.

`curl -kL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.5.0.tar.gz | tar zxvf -
mv googletest-release-1.5.0 gtest
./autogen.sh`